# Locating typesizes.h

Tags: linux, gcc

Where is typesizes.h located?
I've installed the latest gcc build, and I need to set the __FD_SETSIZE to a higher value than 1024.

I tried looking in /usr/lib/bits/, where it should be.
I'm trying to compile UnrealIRCd, can't proceed without changing __FD_SETSIZE.

Does anyone know why I'm missing typesize.h?

Thanks for any help received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
locate typesizes.h
```

It should give you the path where the file is located

Comment: Which gcc version are you using? and which distro?

Comment: Try installing the linux headers again separately. If you are using ubunutu   <br/> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)   <br/> or if you're using fedora/red hat, etc.,   <br/> yum install linux-headers-`uname -r`

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.6.3 on ubuntu server 12.10.
linux headers are up to date.

Comment: I hate myself for suggesting something as horrible as this. But give it a try. First locate the bits folder. It should be either in /usr/lib or in some nested folder in /usr/include. locate bits/types.h should give you the location of bits folder. Now go to that folder and create typesizes.h file in it. Google for the file and copy the data into it. It is an interface kind of file and should not interfere with any of the system functionalities.

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MHX/Convert-Binary-C-0.73/tests/include/include/bits/typesizes.h                                                                        Just try copy pasting this file into bits folder.

Comment: the problem is that there are no folder named bits, tried a locate with no results. I can find allot of types.h but no bits folder. Does the file need too be inside that specific folder anyway?

Comment: I'm gonna try too compile glibc too see if that fix my problem

Comment: If nothing works, try this ----- 
1) go to /usr folder 
2) grep -R "__FD_SETSIZE" include/ | grep 1024   
3) grep -R "__FD_SETSIZE" lib/ | grep 1024   
If you get any results in any of these grep searches, edit those values from 1024 to 4096 (or whatever the value you want to change it to)

That's all I've got. Sorry

Comment: I fixed it, installed linux-libc-dev from dpkg, and now I have the required files.
Thanks for your help though :)